# After Game Center matchmaking my app switches to the default game view instead of the current game joined

Tags: ios, segue, game-center

I am able to press the Find Game button and Game Center matchmaking is successful. I have the segue set to Modal. After a match is found I want it to transition to that match in another view controller (GamePlayScene). Now it currently does this but, slightly wrong. Instead of taking the user to the current game they just joined, it just displays the game layout with no interaction, not the actual game just joined.

```
// viewcontroller.m (Main Menu)

- (IBAction)findGame:(UIButton *)sender {

[[GameKitHelper sharedInstance]
 findMatchWithMinPlayers:2 maxPlayers:2 viewController:self]; // Start matchmaking when pressing the find game button
}
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"GamePlayScene"])
    {
        GameViewController *c = (GameViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        c.match = [GameKitHelper sharedInstance].currentMatch;
    }
}

// GameKitHelper.m

- (void)turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:(GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController *)viewController didFindMatch:(GKTurnBasedMatch *)match
{
    [presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [presentingViewController performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GamePlayScene" sender:match];

    self.currentMatch = match;
```

Comment: Your GameViewController probably just creates a new scene when you present it. Post that code. It should be guarded with a `if (skView.scene == nil { /* create & present scene here */ }`

Comment: Searched my project, no results.